# Angular Observable unkown not assignable. using firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am using Angular 8 to make a todo app with a firebase backend.

This is my todo service file which contains the error stating:

```
Type `Observable unknown[]` is not assignable to type `Observable ITodo[]`.

Type `unknown[]` is not assignable to type `ITodo[]`.

Type `{}` is missing the following properties from type `ITodo`: task, completed
```

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ITodo } from './models/todo';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodosService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  createTodo() {
    return this.db.list('Todos').push({
      task: 'clean',
      completed: 'false'
    });
  }

  getTodo(): Observable<ITodo[]>{
    return this.db.list('Todos').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

My interface looks like this:

```
export interface ITodo {
    task:string,
    completed: boolean
}
```

Does any one have an idea why I am getting that error? Thanks
note: the error is on my getTodo method.

Comment: Your error says "Type `{}` is missing the following properties from type `ITodo`: task, completed". It looks like the items returned by valueChanges() do not hold any data. Have you made sure that the data returned by valueChanges() has the fields "task" and "completed"?

Comment: I assume that the list function is a generic. Perhaps try to do `this.db.list<ITodo>('Todos').valueChanges()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you didn't specify a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) for the `list` method, which optionally accepts a type variable that you can type the result against.

The full definition of [`AngularFireDatabase#list`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/76f721254bcb4e9db693486332a4a72a7e897f15/src/database/database.ts#L28-L35) is as follows:

```js
list<T>(pathOrRef: PathReference, queryFn?: QueryFn): AngularFireList<T>;
```

And the definition for the [`AngularFireList`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/76f721254bcb4e9db693486332a4a72a7e897f15/src/database/interfaces.ts#L6-L16) interface, which accepts a type variable:

```js
export interface AngularFireList<T> {
  query: DatabaseQuery;
  valueChanges(events?: ChildEvent[]): Observable<T[]>;
  snapshotChanges(events?: ChildEvent[]): Observable<SnapshotAction<T>[]>;
  stateChanges(events?: ChildEvent[]): Observable<SnapshotAction<T>>;
  auditTrail(events?: ChildEvent[]): Observable<SnapshotAction<T>[]>;
  update(item: FirebaseOperation, data: Partial<T>): Promise<void>;
  set(item: FirebaseOperation, data: T): Promise<void>;
  push(data: T): database.ThenableReference;
  remove(item?: FirebaseOperation): Promise<void>;
}
```

As such, you should add a type variable as follows:

```js
getTodo(): Observable<ITodo[]>{
  return this.db.list<ITodo>('Todos').valueChanges();
}
```

It's also stated in the "[Retrieving data as lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#create-a-list-binding)" documentation:

> Data is retrieved through the `AngularFireDatabase` service. The service is also generic. Provide the singular type and not the array type.
>
> ```js
> const listRef = db.list('items');
> const shirtsRef = db.list<Shirt>('shirts');
> ```